# How do I know if a tweet is "promoted" through twitter4j API?

Tags: api, rest, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I am using REST API through twitter4j, in Java and I am collecting a tweets dataset. Is there any method or any field in the returned tweets, in twitter4j, from which I will be able to understand that a specific tweet is an ad ("promoted") or not?

Thank you in advance
-Michael

Comment: I have the same question.